# disable Parent window on window.open and re enable on close of popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a parent window where i open up a Popup window on click of a button:

```
function Test() 
    {
            $("body").append('<div id="modalPopUp" class="modalOverlay">');
          var popupWindow = window.open("test.aspx", 'popUpWindow', 'height=300,width=600,left=100,top=30,resizable=No,scrollbars=No,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no, status=No');

        }
```

Right now i am able to open up popup and disable parent window, but now i want to catch close button click + click outside of popup events on Popup window, so i can remove  ModalPopUp from my body so i can re eanble parent div. How do i achieve that?

Comment: have you researched any of the jQuery modal plugins?  I just did a quick search and found this link: http://www.queness.com/post/77/simple-jquery-modal-window-tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can access the parent window in your popup Window using the window.opener object, or:
2. You can access the child window from the parent with the popupWindow object. e.g if the popup closes you can register the unload event in your parent window as such:

   popupWindow.onunload = function() { alert('popup was closed or redirected') }